# RESTFul OAuth with FOSOAuthServer / FOSRest & FOSUser

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm having difficulties to fully understand the concept of the client creation explained [here](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/).
I followed the post to set up the OAuthBundle, and tried to make the changes needed to comply with FOSUser. Though I'm not sure it's perfect.

**My situation**

- My Website is a RESTFul API, which return json or xml only. My frontend will be in AngularJS
- I combined FOSUser, FOSRest and FOSOAuth, it's possible I'm having errors in the configuration.

**The Problem**

I finished setting up the first part of the article up to the `doctrine:schema:update` command. Now I'm supposed to create a client.

How can I set the security for parts of the `^/api` for differents ROLES ?

**example:**

- Anonymous users can access POST `/api/users` but not GET /api/users.
- Only users with `ROLE_ADMIN` can access DELETE `/api/users/{id}`

For testing I'm using [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/docs) (that support OAuth1 & 2, along with other means of auth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using expressions in security.yml

In order to secure certain routes by a conditional combination of **(request)-method** *AND* **(user)-role** ...

... you can make use of **[Expressions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/expression/expressions.html)** in your `security.yml`.

More information can be found in the documentation chapter **[Securing by an Expression](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-by-an-expression)**.

### Example

Only users with role `ROLE_ADMIN` shall be allowed to access `/api/users/{id}` using a `DELETE` request:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - path: "^/api/users/\d+$"
          allow_if: "'DELETE' == request.getMethod() and has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')"
```

**Regex explanation**

- `^` begins with
- `\d+` one or more digits (= user id)
- `$` string end

Comment: Thanks ! About the edit, you deleted the question I was the most interested in =(
I will ask it on another topic, can I send you the link via PM ?